# Aligning Text in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to horizontally align three images with text underneath using CSS.

I have tried various methods but each keeps returning the images vertically aligned and the text not aligned with the images.

```css
#img_cont {
    display: table;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
    
#img_cont a {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    width: 16%;
}
    
#img_cont img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 150px;
}
 
.reviews_block {
    background: #F04950 url('images/layout/love_hearts.png') center;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -9px 11px -5px rgba(104, 12, 16,.5), inset 0 9px 11px -5px rgba(104, 12, 16,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -9px 11px -5px rgba(104, 12, 16,.5), inset 0 9px 11px -5px rgba(104, 12, 16,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -9px 11px -5px rgba(104, 12, 16,.5), inset 0 9px 11px -5px rgba(104, 12, 16,.5);
} 
     
.reviews_block a {
    color: #F5F5F5;
}
        
.reviews_block .reviews .section_content {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 3%;
}
    
.reviews_block .reviews {
    text-align: center;
}
   
.reviews_block .reviews img {
    width: auto;
}
    
.reviews_block .reviews .reviewer_pic {
    background: #FFF;
    display: table;
    margin: 2em auto;
    padding: .5em;
    border: 1px solid #F76F80;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
    
.reviews_block .reviews .reviewer_pic img {
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
 
.reviewer_info p {
    line-height: 150%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
   
.review_rating {
    display: table;
    font-size: 200%;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
    
.review_content {
    max-width: 650px;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 130%;
    line-height: 150%;
}
    
.review_pullquote {
    margin: .5em 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 120%;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 200%;        
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 250%;
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p id="img_cont">
    <a href="#"><img src="/wp-content/themes/webbie/images/write13.png" <p> Sample text here. </a></p>
    <a href="#"><img src="/wp-content/themes/webbie/images/write13.png" <p> Sample text here. </a></p>
    <a href="#"><img src="/wp-content/themes/webbie/images/write13.png" <p> Sample text here. </a></p>
</p>
```

Comment: I believe the issue may be you to the max-width on the DIV but even changing the width of the div container doesn't let me arrange the three images horizontally.

Comment: Firstly your HTML is invalid...paragraphs cannot contain other paragraphs.

Comment: You should add absolute urls to your images. As you can see, they are not loaded. Also, your intent is not clear. What is the desired output? Images with texts underneath aligned in three columns (side-by-side)? Or all 6 elements center-aligned one under the other?

Comment: @Paulie_D: that's the least of his problems. `img` tags are not closed! I didn't correct, as they are part of the problem. It would have meant attemting to solve it.

Comment: in **review_pullquote** why you should use two font-size , font-height , font-weight ????

Comment: Your entire HTML markup is wrong. `p`tags can't be nested inside other `p` and also you are not closing them properly, neither do `img` tags

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is not valid `HTML`.

1. You should close your `img` tags using `>`.
2. You shouldn't have `p` tags nested in other `p` tags.
3. Your `<p>` tags are intertwined with the `<a>` tags.

---

Now, assuming you want 3 columnns side by side, here are a few solutions:

I. Using floats:

```css
#img_cont > * {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#img_cont > a > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="img_cont">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/generic-brands.jpg" />
    <p>Sample text here.</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/generic-brands.jpg" />
    <p>Sample text here.</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/generic-brands.jpg" />
    <p>Sample text here.</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

II. Using flexbox:

```css
#img_cont {
  display: flex;
}
#img_cont > * {
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#img_cont > a > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="img_cont">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/generic-brands.jpg" />
    <p>Sample text here.</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/generic-brands.jpg" />
    <p>Sample text here.</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/generic-brands.jpg" />
    <p>Sample text here.</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

<strike>III. Using html tables</strike>

*Do not use tables for layout*. It is **bad** coding practice. (It used to be the *wrong but working* cross browser solution. However, word is out that Chrome developers (Chrome has currently a market share of more than 50%) are currently considering implementing ways to discourage the use of `table` elements for anything other than tabular data). In short, **don't use it**!

Answer (score 1):

```
<p id="img_cont">
  <a href="#"><img src="/wp-content/themes/webbie/images/write13.png" <p> Sample text here. </a></p>
  <a href="#"><img src="/wp-content/themes/webbie/images/write13.png" <p> Sample text here. </a></p>
  <a href="#"><img src="/wp-content/themes/webbie/images/write13.png" <p> Sample text here. </a></p>
</p>
```

Is very wrong.
Change to this:

```
 <p id="img_cont">
  <a href="#"><img src="/wp-content/themes/webbie/images/write13.png"> <p> Sample text here. </p></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="/wp-content/themes/webbie/images/write13.png"> <p> Sample text here. </p></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="/wp-content/themes/webbie/images/write13.png"> <p> Sample text here. </p></a>
</p>
```

It will not fix your problem, but it will improve some things at least.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

http://jsbin.com/cadikaveme/edit?html,css,output

I have added two style

```
#outterID{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

and

```
.demo{
  float:left;
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

Now its working exactly the way you wanted.